# Show that the following functional is Frechet differentiable

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am new to this and I need to show that the following functional is Frechet differentiable:

\begin{equation}
f(u) = \sin(u(1)) \ \ in \ \ C[0,1]
\end{equation}

What I have already done:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\|F(u+h)-F(u)-Ah\|_{V}}{\|h\|_{U}} = 0
\end{equation}

Gateaux derivative:
$$\begin{split}
A = F'_{G}(u)=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{F(u+th)-F(u)}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin(u(1)+th(1))-\sin(u(1))}{t} \\ = \frac{d}{dt} \sin(u(1)+th(1)) \arrowvert_{t=0} = \cos(u(1)+th(1))\cdot h(1) \arrowvert_{t=0} \\ = \cos(u(1))\cdot h(1)
\end{split}
$$

Substituting $A$ back:
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\|F(u+h)-F(u)-\cos(u(1))\cdot h(1)\|_{V}}{\|h\|_{U}} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\|\sin(u(1)+h(1))-\sin(u(1))-\cos(u(1))\cdot h(1)\|_{V}}{\|h\|_{U}}
$$
That's it, I don't know how to continue...
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: see add commnet button under Mercy's answer. You shoud post your question assressed to Mercy there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $u, h \in C([0,1])$ we have
$$
f(u+h)=\sin(u(1)+h(1))=\sin(u(1))+h(1)(\sin)'(u(1))+\frac12h^2(1)(\sin)''(u(1))+o(h^2(1)),
$$
i.e.
$$
f(u+h)=f(u)+h(1)\cos(u(1))-\frac{h^2(1)}{2}\sin(u(1))+o(h^2(1)).
$$
Since
$$
|h(1)| \le \|h\|_\infty \to 0\, \text{ as }\, h \to 0,
$$
it follows that
$$
f(u+h)=f(u)+h(1)\cos(u(1))+o(\|h\|_\infty).
$$
Thus $f$ is Fréchet differentiable and
$$
Df(u)\cdot h=h(1)\cos(u(1)) \quad \forall u, h \in C([0,1]).
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Mercy. Can you please clarify me a bit, as I don't really understand everything. As far as I understand you used Tailor expansion and Frechet differentiability formula: \begin{equation}
F(u+h)=F(u)+Ah+r(u,h)
\end{equation} to prove that it is differentiable. Is it true?

Comment: @michael: please visit [this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/contact) and request that your two accounts be merged. This way you should be able to post comments on answers given to your own question.